# Emulate Oracle DB server to provide external callback

Tags: oracle, database-server

I am trying to think of a solution to provide my own callback to events which can only be pushed to an Oracle Database server (configuration parameters are ip, port, user, pass) by an external server.

I have been told that, if i did have an Oracle DB server, i could provide my callback using a script like this :

```
open SQL connection.
exec my_own_callback("parameter1");
close conn;
```

Is there any available tool to emulate an Oracle Database server *just enough* so that the function `my_own_callback`, provided in a shared library, is called whenever an event is pushed by the external platform ?

I have searched the web for such alternatives, but could not find any (yet ?).

Comment: Emulate from a networking up standpoint? As in, this service would connect into your "fake oracle db" via sql-net? If so, then not likely. Look at XE db install (free) if oracle db is truly the only destination type available.

Comment: Yes, i need exactly what you describe. If i were to install XE db, how difficult would it be to convert the stored procedure call into a shared-library function call ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_extern_proc.htm

Comment: @Mat your link now returns a 404 but I'd like to know what point were you trying to make?